# How do you detect when a user commits a JComboBox selection via mouse click in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, mouse, jcombobox

I've spent over a day now trying to figure this out. I've tried MouseListener, ItemListener, and ActionListener examples I've found, but none seem to do what I need.

Here's what I've got: I've got a JComboBox that works well.  The user can type in the text box and it autocompletes, and there's a drop-down and everything.  The purpose of the box is for performing searches.  The user types a search and hits enter, which causes the search results to be highlighted in the main pane.  The user can also arrow through the drop-down and initiate the result highlight by hitting enter from the dropdown.

Here's the problem: The user can click an item in the dropdown under the text field and the text field fills in with that value, but the search results are not highlighted.  The user still has to hit enter after having clicked what they want.

Here's what I want: I want to detect the moment the user clicks the dropdown menu item they want so that I can use that event to call my method which highlights the result in the main pane.  I don't want them to have to hit the enter key after clicking an item in the dropdown.

I've got a key adapter that catches the enter-key press to call the method which highlights results and it works well.  The method it calls is called seekAll().

When I tried the mouse listener, it only seemed to work on the text field and not the dropdown.  When I tried the ItemListener, I could not distinguish between items being highlighted/hovered/arrowed across and the click making the drop-down menu selection.  The result of the action listener was similar to my attempt with the ItemListener.

Here's an example of the ActionListener I tried:

```
public abstract class HeaderFinderBox {
    private WideComboBox searchTermBox;
    public HeaderFinderBox() {
        final String[] labels = setupData();
        //just returns an array of strings

        this.searchTermBox = GUIFactory.createWideComboBox(labels);
        searchTermBox.setEditable(true);
        searchTermBox.setBorder(null);
        searchTermBox.setBackground(GUIFactory.DARK_BG);
        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(searchTermBox);

        //This adds my key listener
        //searchTermBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()
        //      .addKeyListener(new BoxKeyListener());

        searchTermBox.addActionListener(new SearchListener());
    }

    class SearchListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LogBuffer.println("Action performed on item from the combo box");
            //seekAll();
        }
    }
}
```

I commented the call to seekAll() because I get null pointer exceptions when the you type your first character into the text box and the field blanks.  With that call commented out, I get the "Action performed on item from the combo box" message whenever these things happen:

1. Twice for each character typed on the keyboard
2. Once when you hit enter
3. 3 times when you click an item in the dropdown
4. 3 times after arrowing to an item in the dropdown and then hitting enter

The only one of these that I want a single hook for doing something is 1 firing upon the user clicking an item in the dropdown.  That would be number 3 in the list above, but it fires 3 times for a single click.  And how do I differentiate that event from all the others (1, 2, & 4)?

If ActionListener is supposed to be able to ONLY give me a single actionPerformed upon click of an item in the dropdown, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is a `Focus Listener`? `JComboBox.addFocusListener()`

Comment: Hmmm, Focus Listener appears to be for detecting when a component gets/loses keyboard focus. I want to detect clicks on items of the dropdown menu.

Comment: Ahh yeah you're right sorry. But im quite sure its suppose to be `ActionListener` you sure you doing it right?

Comment: Use a ActionListener, which will tell you when the selected value is changed. Can you please provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Alright, let me return to ActionListener then. I'm sure I must have done something wrong. Let me implement it, then I'll post the code and describe what goes wrong...

Comment: Not sure how to create a small runnable example. I'm fairly new to java and I jumped in to help on an existing project, so setting up something brand new seems slightly bewildering to me. It's probably easy, I just haven't tried to do it before. I'm a perl guy and this is really my first foray into GUIs. I put up a snippet which you might be able to interpret.

Comment: So if I'm using eclipse and I want to create a small runnable example, would I create a separate new project, or does eclipse have some slick way of creating a 1-off little program? I think I could just put a series of random strings as the labels, fill in the imports, and is that it? Do I have to create some sort of layout or can that be automated?

Comment: Well, I figured out a really hacky way to do it. Still looking for a respectable solution however...

Comment: @hepcat72 I am struggling with the same issue. what's the solution you found? Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm. It’s been too long for me to recall, however, the project is open source. If you can filter through unrelated code to find what you need, feel free to dig through it or even run the app to see if it behaves the way you want. The search boxes aren’t perfect, but I do recall I solved this issue to my satisfaction. The code is on bitbucket: treeview.princeton.edu